# Android dialog dismiss after certain computation

Tags: java, android, dialog

I'm encountering the following problem:

I created a waiting spinner using Dialog like this

```
final Dialog progDialog = new Dialog(context);
progDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);
progDialog.setTitle("Calculating...");
progDialog.setCancelable(false);
progDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = progDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.dimAmount = 0.7f;
progDialog.show();
```

Afterwards, I'm calculating something in the background

```
for()...
    for()...
```

After the calculation is finished, I want to dismiss my dialog with

```
progDialog.dismiss();
```

However, this results in my dialog never being shown at all. When I remove the last line, the dialog is shown but is never dismissed. Is there a fix to it?

Comment: I think your computation is fast enough to not see the dialog progress ,

Comment: It's not, because after dismissing, I start a new activity. Without the last line, the dialog is shown for like 1 second before starting the activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better try with [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progDialog;

    public YourAsyncTask(MyMainActivity activity) {
        progDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       progDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);
       progDialog.setTitle("Calculating...");
       progDialog.setCancelable(false);
       progDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

       progDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        // do background work here
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         // do UI work here
        if (progDialog.isShowing()) {
            progDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Use the above code in your Main Activity. And, do your calculation part in `doInBackground`.

To set timer for your computation try below code:

```
 Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            progDialog.cancel();
        }
    };

    Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
    pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 3000);
```

Adding show/hide:

```
progDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        theLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

**Update**:

ProgressDialog class was deprecated as of API 26

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I implemented it and it works like intended. However, it feels very slow as my computation now takes like 10 seconds (~1-2 seconds before). Is there a way to improve the computation speed?

Comment: Hi @MDaniel I've updated above answer with code which you can use to set timer for your dialog, give it a try.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for